# Divisibility property proof: If $e\mid ab$, $e\mid cd$ and $e\mid ac+bd$ then $e\mid ac$ and $e\mid bd$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a,b,c,d,e\in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $e\mid ab$, $e\mid cd$ and $e\mid ac+bd$ then $e\mid ac$ and $e\mid bd$.

I could use some hints on how to prove this property.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\,m = ac/e,\ n = bd/e.\,$ By hypothesis $\, \color{#c00}{m+n,\, mn \in \Bbb Z}\,$ and $\,m,n\,$ are roots of $\,(x-m)(x-n).\,$ This has  $\color{#c00}{\rm integer}\,$ coeffs so, by the [Rational Root Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) $\,m,n\in\Bbb Z,\,$ so $\ e\mid ac,bd.$

Comment: If I understand correctly, shouldn't $m$ be $ab/e$ and $n$ be $cd/e$??

Comment: @S.C. No, what's written is correct. It is already given that $\,ab/e\,$ and $\,cd/e\,$ are integers.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So the question basically asks : If $m,n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $m+n \in\mathbb{Z}$ and $mn\in \mathbb{Z}$, then prove $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$?? We can easily see that $(m-n )^2\in\mathbb{Z}$. This says $m-n\in\mathbb{Z}$. From here, we have $m^{2}-n^{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Also $m^{2}+n^{2}$. This says $2m^{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$ from here we get $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Is this ok?

Comment: @S.C. Yes, that works, but you must justify *all* of those inferences. The Rational Root Test generalizes these inferences, and has a simpler proof.